# Assigning value of a button to variable in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have three buttons, and I want to add the ID of clicked button into a variable, so it could be used later. What am I doing wrong?

Currently my code is as follows:

```js
var userInput = function getInput(clicked_id) {
  var input = clicked_id;
  return input;
  console.log(input);
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to console after the return statement?Try console above the return and check if it is working

Comment: what object is `clicked_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a function and assigning that to a variable .Try like this

```
var userInput ;   

function getInput(clicked_id){ 
    userInput  = clicked_id;
    console.log(userInput  );
 }
```

OR you can use like

```js
   function getInput(clicked_id) {
      var input = clicked_id;
      return input;
      console.log(input);
    }

 var userInput = getInput('someText')
 console.log(userInput);
```

in your code you have created variable `userInput`  and assigned a function to it.Check the snippet below to find the value of user input

```js
var userInput = function getInput(clicked_id) {
  var input = clicked_id;
  return input;
  console.log(input);
}

console.log(userInput)
```